# How to change timeline scale in Davinci Resolve Fusion page?

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am watching a tutorial about creating an animated title. The instructor shows his time line as A, however, mine is shown as B.

How to change from B to A? I have searched for this but I could not find the proper settings on my installed Davinci Resolve 17 (the latest update, free version).

[image]

Comment: Why is mine negative?

Comment: Not sure, but if I had to guess, I'd say that Fusion is showing a point in time that's a few minutes before the clip's boundaries in Resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the preview scale using the numbers below the transport controls. When fusion clips come in from Resolve, Resolve determines the in and out points, based on where the clip sits in your timeline.  So changing the numbers to match a tutorial you’re following is probably not a good idea unless you’re using identical media, and have identical Resolve timelines.